# Which way should I choose to inflate view in ViewPager's instantiateItem method?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, inflate

I write a Android application using ViewPager. And now, I have a confusion when use ViewPager.
When I use the code below to inflate a view from a layout xml file and add it into viewpager.

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
     View view = View.inflate(ShareTasksActivity.this, R.layout.item_internal_advertisement, null);
     container.addView(view);
     return view;
}
```

But When I use code below, the viewpager will show nothing.

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {    
     View view = View.inflate(ShareTasksActivity.this, R.layout.item_internal_advertisement, container);
     return view;
}
```

I think the two snippets do the same thing, but the results are different. I don't know why. Can anyone help me ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Actually, these snippets are doing slightly different things:

1. Inflates view and add it to the container;
2. Just inflates view;

The issue here is the following:

call to `View.inflate(ShareTasksActivity.this, R.layout.item_internal_advertisement, container);` is equal to the following one: `LayoutInflater.from(ShareTasksActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.item_internal_advertisement, container, false);` (checkout [its source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java)). The same time [instantiateItem() documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#instantiateItem%28android.view.ViewGroup,%20int%29) mentions:

> The adapter is responsible for adding the view to the container given
>   here

So, second variant doesn't work at all because it is not adding view to the container.

However, first variant per mine understanding also has an issue: layout parameters You might provide for top level view `R.layout.item_internal_advertisement` will not be applied if You provide `null` parent view.